# How to perform simple grid search with Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I tried to use Scikit Learn's GridSearch class to tune the hyper parameters of my logistic regression algorithm.

However GridSearch, even when using multiple jobs in parallel, takes literally days to process unless you are only tuning one parameter. I thought about using Apache Spark to speed this process up, but I have two questions.

- In order to use Apache Spark, do you literally need multiple machines to distribute the workload ? For example, if you only have 1 laptop, is it pointless to use Apache Spark ?
- Is there a simple way to use Scikit Learn's GridSearch in Apache Spark ?

I have read the documentation, but it talks about running parallel workers on an entire machine learning pipeline, but I just want it for the parameter tuning.

**Imports**

```
import datetime
%matplotlib inline

import pylab
import pandas as pd
import math
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab

import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

from sklearn import datasets, tree, metrics, model_selection
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LinearRegression, Perceptron
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2, VarianceThreshold, RFE
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier, VotingClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

from datetime import datetime as dt
import scipy
import itertools

ucb_w_reindex = pd.read_csv('clean_airbnb.csv')
ucb = pd.read_csv('clean_airbnb.csv')

pylab.rcParams[ 'figure.figsize' ] = 15 , 10
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

new_style = {'grid': False}
plt.rc('axes', **new_style)
```

**Algorithm Hyper Parameter Tuning**

```
X = ucb.drop('country_destination', axis=1)
y = ucb['country_destination'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .3, random_state=42, stratify=y)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

parameters = {'leaf_size': range(1, 100), 'n_neighbors': range(1, 10), 'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'], 
              'algorithm': ['kd_tree', 'ball_tree', 'brute', 'auto']}


# ======== What I want to do in Apache Spark ========= #

%%time
parameters = {'n_neighbors': range(1, 100)}
clf1 = GridSearchCV(estimator=knn, param_grid=parameters, n_jobs=5).fit(X_train, y_train)
best = clf1.best_estimator_

# ==================================================== #
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library called [spark-sklearn](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn) to run distributed parameter sweeps. You're correct in that you'd need a cluster of machines, or a single multi-CPU machine to get parallel speedup.

Hope this helps,

Roope - Microsoft [MMLSpark](https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark) Team